# Doing http request with silent notification

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use silent push notification in my app. I enabled background modes on my app and phone.

When silent notification arrives `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate method is calling. But I can't do any http request in this method. I am using following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("step 1")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "url")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "search=\(username)&me=\(anonId)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        print("step 2")
        if error == nil {
            let jsonResult: Dictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let results = jsonResult["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
            print(results)
            for item in results {

            }
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
        }
    }
}
```

When notification arrives, I see `step 1` text on console. But I can't see `step 2` text.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up an URL session that supports background downloading and use that. Search on "Background" in the `NSURLSession` class reference for info on how to do that.

I don't think you will have to ask for background time in order to initiate the background download. You should have enough time to do that.

Comment: Can you give an little example?